# javascript: array with unknown length and unknown index names

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a program of a football league.

A example of a league:

team1
team2
team3

I want to save (increase) number of players for each team like

```
var teamArray = [];
teamArray[team1] = 1;
teamArray[team2] = 2;
```

and I am doing in the body of some functions like:

```
function 1(){}
function 2(){}
function .(){}
function .(){}
function .(){}
function n(){}
```

but this works only when i "teach" javscript that the array is an integer array... with somethin like

```
teamArray[team1] = 0;
teamArray[team1] = teamArray[team1] + 1;
```

but the problem is every time when i come to one of my functions, i have to set my array element to 0 and that makes the whole calculation wrong...

Could anyone give me a hint please?

My Idea was to was to set each array element to 0 from the beginning, but i dont know at the beginning of my game how many teams i will have today, that why i implemented the array like:

```
var teamArray = [];
```

Comment: `teamArray.push( teamArray.length )`

Comment: You're not using the array as an array; you're treating it like a plain object. JavaScript arrays can be whatever length you want, but the only properties that count towards the length are those with numeric names.

Comment: Are you coming from a PHP background? You want `teamArray` to be an object, not an array. In JS, arrays are linear and only have numerical indexes.

Comment: `function .(){}` is that javascript?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, he means `...` in a vertical way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JavaScript object instead. Something like:

```
var teamObject = {
   team1: 3,
   team2: 5,
   team3: 7,
};
```

Or, perhaps an array of objects:

```
var teamArray = [
   { name: 'team1', players: 3 },
   { name: 'team2', players: 5 },
   { name: 'team3', players: 7 }
];
```

The object is easier to access if all you want is to get or set the number of players:

```
teamObject.team1 += 1;
```

but an array is easier to loop through and can be ordered:

```
for (var i=0,j=teamArray.length; i<j; i++) {
  console.log(teamArray[i].name + " has " + teamArray[i].players + " players");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the number of team members by testing the current number first, and if it does not exist, you initialise it with 0 on the fly. All that can be done in one expression with a logical OR (`||`):

```
 teamArray[team1] = (teamArray[team1] || 0) + 1;
```

This will not destroy the previous value you had and work like a simple `+ 1` in that case.

You should define your `teamArray` as object, although it will work with array as well (since that is an object as well):

```
 teamArray = {}
```

The name is then of course a bit confusing, but I'll stick with it.

Whenever you need to iterate over the teams you have collected, then you can use a `for` loop like this:

```
for (var team in teamArray) {
    console.log(team, teamArray[team]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help!

I did it like this now:

```
var listItems = $("#teamsDropdown li");
    listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
        var team = $(li).text();
        TeamPlayerQuantities[team] = 0;             
    });
```

and increasing the qnty of players wiht functions like:

```
function1(team){
    TeamPlayerQuantities[team] ++;
}
```

Comment: There were no `listItems` in the question, so why do you introduce them in your answer? If that was essential, it should have been mentioned in the question. Here you set the numbers to zero, which in your question you said (in a final highlight) was not possible, because "*... i dont know at the beginning of my game how many teams i will have today...*". So apparently, you do know.

Comment: normally i dont know, but with a lil trick (read out the List Elements of my HTML part) I could find out the teams and could create an array and set the teamPlayers to 0 at the beginning (befor the user adds a players from team1 or team2)

sorry for the mistunderstanding or complicated description!